# How to get same output for parallelization for any number of threads in OpenMP for if-else, increment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to parallelize the following code without any **atomic** operation or **critical** section.

My code is given below which I have already tried but outcome is not expected. For any number of threads I want same output where order of output may be different i.e., 5th line using 1 thread may appear in 8th line while using 4 threads. Here, critical section is k++ region if I do not mistake. Please suggest how can I do that in OpenMP without using critical/atomic like clause.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "omp.h"
#include "cstdlib"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int t = atoi(argv[1]);
    vector<int> A{0,3,5,7};
    vector<int> B{1,2,3,0,3,0,3,0,1,2};
    int k = 0, j;
    for(int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++){
        k = A[i];
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(t)
        for(j = 0; j < A.size(); j++){
        if(j == B[k]){
            printf("i(yes):%d # B[%d] = %d, thread = %d\n",i, k, B[k], omp_get_thread_num());
            if(k < B.size() && k < A[i+1]){
                k++;
            }
        }else{
            printf("i(no):%d # j = %d, k = %d, thread =  %d\n",i, j, k, omp_get_thread_num());
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

`

When I run using 1 thread I get the following output:

```
$ ./a.out 1
i(no):0 # j = 0, k = 0, thread =  0
i(yes):0 # B[0] = 1, thread = 0
i(yes):0 # B[1] = 2, thread = 0
i(yes):0 # B[2] = 3, thread = 0
i(yes):1 # B[3] = 0, thread = 0
i(no):1 # j = 1, k = 4, thread =  0
i(no):1 # j = 2, k = 4, thread =  0
i(yes):1 # B[4] = 3, thread = 0
i(yes):2 # B[5] = 0, thread = 0
i(no):2 # j = 1, k = 6, thread =  0
i(no):2 # j = 2, k = 6, thread =  0
i(yes):2 # B[6] = 3, thread = 0
i(yes):3 # B[7] = 0, thread = 0
i(no):3 # j = 1, k = 7, thread =  0
i(no):3 # j = 2, k = 7, thread =  0
i(no):3 # j = 3, k = 7, thread =  0
```

But when I run using 2 threads I get the following output which is not synchronized and expected.

```
$ ./a.out 2
i(no):0 # j = 0, k = 0, thread =  0
i(yes):0 # B[0] = 1, thread = 0
i(no):0 # j = 2, k = 0, thread =  1
i(no):0 # j = 3, k = 1, thread =  1
i(no):1 # j = 2, k = 3, thread =  1
i(no):1 # j = 3, k = 3, thread =  1
i(yes):1 # B[3] = 0, thread = 0 
i(no):1 # j = 1, k = 4, thread =  0
i(no):2 # j = 2, k = 5, thread =  1
i(no):2 # j = 3, k = 5, thread =  1
i(yes):2 # B[5] = 0, thread = 0 
i(no):2 # j = 1, k = 6, thread =  0
i(yes):3 # B[7] = 0, thread = 0
i(no):3 # j = 2, k = 7, thread =  1
i(no):3 # j = 3, k = 7, thread =  1
i(no):3 # j = 1, k = 7, thread =  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't parallelize your loop, with or without atomics.  Since the value of `k` in iteration `j + 1` depends on what happens in iteration `j`, the iterations must run in order.  (Ask yourself how the iteration with `j` == 2 can run properly if the `j` == 1 iteration hasn't incremented `k` yet?)

Your current code has a race on `k`, and its value can change in the middle of an iteration when it is updated by another thread.